# How to solve a system of equations seperated by "and" in maxima?

Tags: maxima

My student gives me an answer in the form:

`x=4 and y=3`

Now I want to find out what x and y is in maxima, and give feedback. For example, "x is correct, but y is incorrect". I know that if the student gives the answer as a list, I can do:

`solve([x=4, y=3], [x,y])`

Is there a way to either convert this `and` expression to a list, or make maxima find out for me what `x` and `y` is directly?

Comment: Which language you want to solve it in and specifically you are treating answer string? If it is string you can use regex

Comment: @RajanChauhan I mean specifically in the maxima language (computer algebra system).

Answer (score 0):

If the input expression is a string, then you can use `parse_string`:

```
a: "x=3 and y = 4"$
inpart(parse_string(a),1);
(%o1)  x = 3

exp: map(lambda([i],inpart(parse_string(a),i)), [1,2]);
(%o2)  [x = 3, y = 4]

solve(exp, [x,y]);
(%o3)  [[x = 3, y = 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can obtain a Maxima expression from the input via `parse_string` or some other means.

Let `e` be the expression. Then `subst("and"="[", e)` returns an expression which has the operator `"["` (i.e., a list) instead of `"and"`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `split`:

```
str:"x=4 and y=3";
spl:split(str,"and");
>>> ["x=4 "," y=3"]
eq:map(parse_string,spl);
>>> [x=4,y=3]
```